# $HOME/bin is not appended to PATH in Linux Mint

Tags: bash, linux-mint, path

I created the folder `$HOME/bin` and put some symbolic links in there.

Furthermore I set the checkbox `Run command as login shell` (according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333446/what-does-run-command-as-a-login-shell-do) question) in the Terminal properties.

Now when I type `echo $PATH` I see that the bin directory wasn't appended to PATH. I tried to put this (which was default):

```
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

into `.bash_profile`, `.profile` and `.bashrc` but nothing worked.

Do you know what's going wrong here?

---

Update: If I open a terminal and run `. ~/.bashrc` the bin directory is appended to PATH correctly. But if I open a terminal and run `. ~/.profile` it is not appended to PATH (for testing I included the if statment above in both of these files).

Furthermore I added `echo "in bashrc"` to `.bashrc` and when I open a terminal it prints "in bashrc", so it doesn't fail at loading bashrc (same test succesfull for `.profile`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the answer to my problem. The following line was in my `.profile`:

`export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:usr/local/bin:...` which of course resets the PATH to this value. That means anything that makes changes to PATH and was above this line just had no effect anymore.

The cause of this problem was the following: Some time ago I modified my `.profile` with the command `echo "export PATH=\"$PATH:$HOME/.npm-packages/bin\"" >> ~/.profile`. I thought it would write `$PATH` as plain text to `.profile` but instead it resolved it to the actual content of PATH. I had to escape the dollar sign (`\$PATH` instead of `$PATH`), now it works like expected.

Answer (score 0):

If it lacks $HOME/bin (or equivalent), the problem is likely in the code you are using to set the PATH. You could check this by commenting out your if/then that sets the PATH and replace it with:

```
echo "just a test" > ~/justatest
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ]; then echo "echo bin found" > ~/bin/testresult; fi
chmod 777 ~/bin/testresult
~/bin/testresult
```

The first line is a sanity check and should never fail. The final lines test the availability of your bin directory. I have used the convention of ~ instead of $PATH -- same thing.

Comment: I already tried something like this, the code is not the problem. Even if I set the line `export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` without the if statement it isn't appended to PATH. And btw I think you mean '~ instead of $HOME', not $PATH

Comment: Yes, ~ substitutes for $HOME; that's right. If you prepend $HOME/bin to PATH as you indicate, then what does `echo $PATH` show once you are logged in?

Comment: It prints all the standard paths like `/usr/bin` and in addition all the custom paths I added by myself to `~/.profile`, like `/home/simon/programs/jdk1.8.0_65/bin`. Everything's just fine except `$HOME/bin`. If I open a terminal and run `export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` and then `echo $PATH` the bin directory is appended to PATH succesfully, but only for the current session.